# Fight breaks out in a restaurant, Hitler salutes in the background

Tags: identify-this-movie, identify-this-tv-show

I believe this is a comedy as the whole scene is rather silly. A fight breaks out in a place with tables, a bar and a stage. It looks kinda retro, with pastel colors and simple shapes. We see various people fighting each others in funny ways, there's food being thrown all over the place. There's Hitler in the background, on the stage, saluting left and right. Some guy slide across the bar's counter and is knocked out by a plank hitting his head. A man in a suit comes out of the bathroom, see the mess, almost get hit by a thrown cake(or pie?), then goes back in the bathroom.

The actors are mostly all whites, there might have been some black people. It's mostly men fighting but there's women in the staff. I do not know the context of the scene as that scene is the only part I've seen.

The video quality was standard 4:3, so it's from before HD video. It's in color, not a cartoon. I've often seen this scene posted as a gif when online communities disagree loudly on a given topic.

Comment: Nice question, lots of details.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's [Blazing Saddles (1974)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0071230/?ref_=nv_sr_1)

Though I can't find a clip of that precise scene, it's documented in ["The Hitler Filmography: Worldwide Feature Film and Television Miniseries"](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=5nYwCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA20&lpg=PA20&dq=Fight%20breaks%20out%20in%20a%20restaurant,%20Hitler%20salutes&source=bl&ots=PP7D5WlaFQ&sig=pLt1b5ADeF052E_t33H1YebziUc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiUoIHPyILOAhXEL8AKHb52DhoQ6AEIKjAC#v=onepage&q=Fight%20breaks%20out%20in%20a%20restaurant%2C%20Hitler%20salutes&f=false) & also the uncredited actor is listed on [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0071230/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast)

I found a still - this would be when he's doing the line
"They lose me after the bunker scene"

[image]

After comments - clip of the main pie fight here on YouTube

Comment: Here,  https://youtu.be/_AOeSrLCD-U